# What does installing from '<nixpkgs>' mean?

Tags: nix

How is `nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -i ...` different to just `nix-env -i ...`?

I would have guessed that nixpkgs is the default source of packages.

Answer (score 0):

It uses `~/.nix-defexpr` by default.

To quote the [`nix-env` man page section of the Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#common-options)

> **`--file` / `-f path`**
>
> Specifies the Nix expression (designated below as the active Nix expression) used by the `--install`, `--upgrade`, and `--query --available` operations to obtain derivations. The default is `~/.nix-defexpr`.